# Do Hermite functions also represent the functions of compact support in Schwartz space?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction

Schwartz space includes wave functions, such as Gaussians (wave function of harmonic oscillator, for instance), that range over all of x, are infinitely differentiable, square integrable from minus infinity to infinity, and vanish faster than any power of x. Schwartz space also includes the smooth functions of compact support (wave function of particle in a box, for instance).

My question is can all of the above Schwartz functions be expanded into the same set of Hermite functions (of course, with different coefficients), or do the smooth functions of compact support require some kind of modified Hermite functions (such as setting them equal to zero outside of a specific interval) vs the Hermite functions used for expansion of Schwartz functions that are not of compact support? I have been trying to research this but have not gotten a clear answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using the same definition of Hermite functions found in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Hermite_functions) Wikipedia article, they form an orthonormal basis of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, so any $L^2$-function can be expanded in them. This includes functions with compact support. (Note though that the partial sums $\sum_{n=0}^N c_n|\psi_n\rangle$ will not have compact support for any finite $N$.)

Comment: @ Mark A Thanks! I just wasn't sure, since I don't think that the Hermite functions, themselves, have compact support, so maybe they could not be the orthogonal expansion of even smooth functions that do.

Comment: @David I guessed that was the confusion :). Although the functions themselves do not have compact support, the limit $N\to \infty$ of partial sums will do.